# Text size in iOS Xcode target is larger than the other target

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder

I need some help with my application.

I have two targets for my iOS application.

- One for Enterprise Deployment (Enterprise In House Dist)
- One for App Store Deployment (Distribution)

These two can't be on the same app store account so we have two Apple Accounts. (It's dumb I know... thanks Apple!)

Anyway, as far as I can tell, the build settings are all the same.... HOWEVER

The text for the Distribution Target is larger. It seems like the whole layout is a little different having a tendency towards larger assets. (See Images Below)

This causes layout issues in our application

I've verified that it isn't related to any iOS Device settings, because it's different on the same device.

I'm completely stumped and dumbfounded. Please help! Any suggestions? I need the distribution target to have the same size assets as the In House Dev target.

Distribution (Store) Build:
[image: Distribution]

In House Dev Build (Enterprise Apple Account):
[image: In House Dev Build]

Comment: Did you try to debug? Maybe it'll get a clue on what's happening

Comment: I assume this 2 screenshots are from the same real device. Am I right?

Comment: Well, I can launch the app in xcode.. But debug what? What am I supposed to debug? Am I supposed to put a breakpoint in the AppDelegate and then pray for guidance?

Comment: Yes they are from the same exact device

Comment: If you are sure both of this views have exactly the same constraints, text sizes. try to put both of this apps on iPhone using xCode (just run project on device) and see if the screens still are not the same.

Comment: It appears that you don't familiar with the views debugger. Run the app with Xcode in device and in the debugger area (above the logs console) click on the button that debug views. That you'll see all the views 3D with their constraints and dimension data. Good debug starting point ;)

Comment: I think I might have figured it out.. one target didn't specify a Launch Screen File. I don't know why that would have caused an issue...

Comment: I think the launch screen file has something with resolution setting... How did you found it?

Comment: It must have something to do with it... It was just compare + check. I don't know why exactly this problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

There was not a Launch Screen file in one of the Targets. I don't know why this would impact the whole application, but it does.

**UPDATE** - Some customers are seeing this, but we don't know why.

Comment: Im having the same problem.  Some weirdly sized components (not all),  only in production, only on some devices. Can you clarify a little what you you did? When you say you added launch screen, what exactly did you add?  Just the default.png files at the different sizes? We want to keep the LaunchScreen as a storyboard if possible. Also, when you wrote your update - are you saying that in the end this solution did NOT work, and some customers are still seeing it after the Launch Image fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is also caused by display zoom, which can be turned on in iOS on device setup, or in Settings -> "Display & Brightness", "Display Zoom".

It literally changes the resolution to be lower. If you screenshot the screen, the resolution will be lower than the advertised resolution.